# Attempt to Dereference to null object on trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, null-pointer

I am trying to update child object(Task) from Parent object(Enrolmentform__c).

When I am trying to stamp the value, I am getting null pointer exception .

```
if(trigger.isafter && Trigger.isinsert)
{
    list<id> EnrolmenFormID=new list<id>();
    for(Task ThisTask : Trigger.new)
    {
        EnrolmenFormID.add(ThisTask.Enrolment_Form_ID__c);  
    }

    Map<id,EnrolmentForm__c> UpdateEnrolmentForm = new Map<id,EnrolmentForm__c>([select id,PostalAddressRef__c,ResidentialAddressRef__c from EnrolmentForm__c where id IN :EnrolmenFormID ]);
    System.debug('updateEnrolmentForm======' +UpdateEnrolmentForm);

    if(UpdateEnrolmentForm.size() > 0)
    {
        for(Task ThisTask : Trigger.new)
        {
            System.debug('postaalref================'+UpdateEnrolmentForm.get(ThisTask.id).PostalAddressRef__c);
            if(ThisTask.Source__c=='SmartRoll')
            {
                if(String.isEmpty(ThisTask.Communication_Address_Support__c) )
                {
                     ThisTask.Communication_Address_Support__c=UpdateEnrolmentForm.get(ThisTask.id).PostalAddressRef__c;
                }
```

This line is throwing the error:

```
ThisTask.Communication_Address_Support__c=UpdateEnrolmentForm.get(ThisTask.id).PostalAddressRef__c;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong map key. Regardless, you should add a check that the key actually finds a value.

```
EnrolmentForm__c form = updateEnrolmentForm.get(thisTask.Enrolment_Form_ID__c);
thisTask.Communication_Address_Support__c = (form == null) ? null : form.PostalAddressRef__c;
```

Be sure to remove your debug statement, as it makes the same mistake.

PS - You have a typo, as it's spelled Enrollment. If you haven't yet deployed this object, now would be the time to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching `PostalAddressRef__c` field for task ID in your object EnrolmentForm__c.Your Map `UpdateEnrolmentForm` does not contain that id (`ThisTask.id`).You should always have a check if the key exists in your map or not with something like below to avoid exceptoin

```
UpdateEnrolmentForm.containsKey(ThisTask.id)
```

Comment: Note that an enrollment form record could never have the same Id as a `Task` record.

Comment: what suppose i have to do if postal address is blank then residential address has to be print i tried the below code but no luck!!!!!!!!if(ThisTask.Source__c=='SmartRoll' && (UpdateEnrolmentForm.containsKey(ThisTask.Enrolment_Form_ID__c) ))
                     {
                if(String.isEmpty(ThisTask.Communication_Address_Support__c))
                {
               ThisTask.Communication_Address_Support__c=UpdateEnrol
              else 
            { Task.Communication_Address_Support__c=UpdateForm.get(ThisTask.Enrolment_Form_ID__c).ResidentialAddressRef__c;  
            }